# Select Sql with space in data

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table where the data looks like below:

```
col1| col2  | col3
101 | AA AB | AAAA
102 | ACA B | AAAA
103 | ACBA  | AAAA
104 | ABCD  | AAAA
```

What I am trying and need is, select all the records that have a space in col2, from the above example, my select should return both 101 and 102. The space isn't a fixed field, it can be in any character.

```
Select * from tableA where col2 like '% %'
```

this does not help me as the '%' will start fetching all records, if I have to use a function substring then my space needs to at a fixed position, which is not in this case.

any suggestions, please

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 select * 
   from tableA 
  where col2 like '%_ _%'
```

use `'%_ _%'` mask instead of `'% %'` to filter out `' ABCD'` as well as `'ABCD '`

Edit: It may happen, that your data have many *trailing spaces*, e.g. `'ABCD     '`; in this case try to ***trim*** the data:

```
  select * 
       from tableA 
      where trim(col2) like '% %'
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry; '%_ _%' does not work, I am still getting all records back, if you meant to suggest have some character instead of '_' then that's not an option since the col2 data need not necessarily always start with A.

Comment: @user3040077: it looks that your data have trailing spaces, e.g. 'ABCD    '; try trimming it (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

On the W3C website, you can try out SQL code. I tried with your '% %' syntax and it returned the expected result.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_wildcard_percent

Comment: '%' is used as a wild character, so if I have it in my select SQL (such as col2 like '% %') what it means is, its going to select all the records where there is something in col2, coz the wild character will consider any value. '%<space>%' is not working because for record 103 it would be %<SPACE>%'= %= ACBA and end it would consider space and again wildcharacter which is nothing.